# Selenium Webdriver won't find element in xblock

Tags: python, html, selenium

I don't know if the question even makes sense - I'm very new to Python and Selenium and coding in general.

The story is I'm trying to automate the process of saving edX course webpages as HTML. I'm using the latest iPython and Webdriver. This is what I've done so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/Khoa_Ngo\bin\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://courses.edx.org/login')

#logging in
driver.find_element_by_id('login-email').send_keys('EMAIL')
driver.find_element_by_id('login-password').send_keys('PASSWORD')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="submit"]').click()

#choosing course
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@href="/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV262x+1T2020a/course/"]').click()
```

What I want to do next is to save the webpage as HTML, store it somewhere, and then click "Next" to proceed to the next course module and repeat. But I can't seem to locate the button. Here is what I've tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/button[2]').click()
```

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sequence_adf942ea-fcee-289c-a1f8-3c557ee5fb15 > div.sequence-nav > button.sequence-nav-button.button-next')
```

I don't think this element is in an iframe. However it's in some kind of "xblock". I'm not sure how that will affect the selection.

This is the webpage I saved: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Zr6sGO0j-H-Tze_lBgkLnQXuQA0pxsWr?usp=sharing

Are these information enough to answer my question? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you post the html of that element you are trying to interact after login?To save it first use `driver.page_source` to get the html and then save it.

Comment: Hi @KunduK. Isn't that the text file I included in the Google Drive link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below xpath :

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sequence-nav-button button-next'][contains(.,'Next')]"))).click()
```

or

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sequence-nav-button-label'][contains(.,'Next')]")))
```

You can also try javascript click::

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
nextbutton= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sequence-nav-button-label'][contains(.,'Next')]")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", nextbutton)
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Can you please also explain why my code didn't work ?